# FOREACH with a DATE COMPARE condition (PHP)

Tags: php, json, loops, foreach

I have a JSON source and I am trying to loop trough it and show some results (up to 9 results) which is not a problem

The problem is that I want to show only the results that are matching a certain date, where the date might be exact or between 2 dates.

For example I want to show only the events where let say the date **2019-11-17** is within **timeFrom timeTo** of the event or **timeFrom** or **timeTo** is equal to it. In that example it will be event 1 and 3

**This is the source sample**

```
{  
      "title":"event 1",
      "timeFrom":"2019-11-16 19:00:00",
      "timeTo":"2019-11-18 22:00:00",
      "listText":"text of the event",
      "url":"https://url",
      "imageUrl":"https://image.jpg",
      "locations":{  
         "title":"Location name",
         "url":"https://location"
      }
   },
      {  
      "title":"event 2",
      "timeFrom":"2019-11-20 19:00:00",
      "timeTo":"2019-11-20 22:00:00",
      "listText":"text of the event",
      "url":"https://url",
      "imageUrl":"https://image.jpg",
      "locations":{  
         "title":"Location name",
         "url":"https://location"
      }
   },
      {  
      "title":"event 3",
      "timeFrom":"2019-11-17 19:00:00",
      "timeTo":"2019-11-17 22:00:00",
      "listText":"text of the event",
      "url":"https://url",
      "imageUrl":"https://image.jpg",
      "locations":{  
         "title":"Location name",
         "url":"https://location"
      }
```

**And this is the foreach I have at the moment**

```
foreach(array_slice($arr, 0, 9) as $data) {  

            //then I will show the result
        }
```

So, I can't figure out how to make that condition within the foreach.

Comment: You could convert all dates to a timestamp and then check if the timeFrom is smaller and timeTo is bigger than your supplied timestamp

Comment: Not sure that that would work for event 3, as the timestamp will be smaller than timeFrom for event 3, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$date = "2019-11-17";

$events = json_decode($json_output, true);

foreach ($events as $event)
{
    if (($date > $event['timeFrom'] && $date < $event['timeTo']) || in_array($date, array($event['timeFrom'], $event['timeTo'])))
    {
        $filtered_events[] = $event;
    }
}


$sliced_events = array_slice($filtered_events, 0, 9);

print_r($sliced_events);
```

Comment: That works fine, but for some reason the array_slice would not work. Any ideas?

Comment: In your code, `array_slice` will just give you the first 9 events and nothing to do about comparing the dates, would you like to include it in my answer?

Comment: yes. That would be great. I will need to have the first 9 that are within the comparison

Comment: But that way it would cut the results before filtering them right?

Comment: Well, I want to cut the results after they are filtered

Comment: Thats exactly what I want to do. Do you know how can I count all the events after filtering?

Comment: Something like this count($event); Is that the best way to do it?

Comment: Thanks a lot.You are a lifesaver :)

Answer (score 2):

This function iterates through the events data, looking for events whose from and to dates surround the given date:

```
function find_events($events, $date) {
    $date = new DateTime($date);
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        $from = (new DateTime($event['timeFrom']))->setTime(0,0,0);
        $to = (new DateTime($event['timeTo']))->setTime(0,0,0);
        if ($date >= $from && $date <= $to) {
            echo "{$event['title']} ({$event['listText']}) from {$event['timeFrom']} to {$event['timeTo']}\n";
        }
    }
}
$events = json_decode($json, true);
find_events($events, '2019-11-17');
```

Output:

```
event 1 (text of the event) from 2019-11-16 19:00:00 to 2019-11-18 22:00:00 
event 3 (text of the event) from 2019-11-17 19:00:00 to 2019-11-17 22:00:00
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/qEh2r)

Comment: For this particular set of data you can compare dates as strings, since they are in appropriate format for that :)

Comment: @Styx In this case you're absolutely right. I did need to strip the times from the dates in the JSON but I could have done that with a `substr`. This method should be more reliable in case the date format isn't exactly `Y-m-d H:i:s`